# Flag options of createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am using node js to write text file to disk :

```
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

var path = directory + '/cpu.log';

var a = fs.createWriteStream(path, {
            flags: 'a'
        });

a.write('test string');
```

What are the options for `flags: 'foo'`

I could not find the alternatives in [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are documented in `fs.open` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

For `fs.createWriteStream` of course you'll be interested in the flags for writing, such as `w` for write, `a` for append.

The docs hint that you can also use a number representing the flags from Linux Open(2). You can get a list of common ones with:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.constants
// { O_RDONLY: 0,
//   O_WRONLY: 1,
//   O_RDWR: 2,
//    ...
```

But you should probably stick with the normal `r`, `w`, `a` etc. unless you have a compelling reason not to.